# How to compare two columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, case

Suppose I have a dataframe like this.

```
yyyymm.  beta zerotrade beta_breakpoint zerotrade_breakpoint
197001    13.    27.        15.             25
197002.   11.    13.        17.             23
```

I need to compare beta with beta_breakpoint, zerotrade with zerotrade_breakpoint. If beta is bigger than beta_breakpoint, create a new column called "low",if smaller, return "high".
I want an output like this.

```
yyyymm.  beta zerotrade beta_breakpoint zerotrade_breakpoint. beta_portfolio.  zerotrade_portfolio
197001    13.    27.        15.             25.                   low.            high
197002.   11.    13.        17.             23.                   low.            low
```

I've tried this code, but it didn't work. Suppose I call the dataframe "data2".

```
data3 <- data2 %>%
  mutate(across(c(beta,zerotrade),~ case_when(.<=._breakpoint ~ "low",
                                               .>._breakpoint ~ "high")))
```

Comment: What goes in the column `low` when beta is bigger? What goes in the column when beta is smaller? How are zerotrade and zerotrade_breakpoint being compared? Please provide an example of the output you're aiming for.

Comment: This is an incredibly basic question - This should easily be solvable by searching the site or just the internet.  Please also show what you have already tried.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximize your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  may help.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have lots of columns to calculate this for, the simple solution is probably best. Create each column individually with a simple `ifelse` statement:

```r
data3 <- data2 %>%
  mutate(beta_portfolio = ifelse(beta>beta_breakpoint, "high", "low")) %>%
  mutate(zerotrade_portfolio = ifelse(zerotrade>zerotrade_breakpoint, "high", "low"))
```

Comment: I do have a lot of columns to calculate.